# Is android.test deprecated

Tags: android, android-studio

Is the android.test library deprecated?

[image]

I have a few tests under androidTest folder but I can't seem to find this library at all. Even in the project structure on Android studio, I can't find this library. Initially I tried to use this library by following the following document https://developer.android.com/training/testing/set-up-project but then I realized that the library itself was missing. How do I get this library? I am basically interested in the MockContentResolver class that this library allows me to mock. Any help is appreciated. Please let me know how do I go about this. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the native testing library is deprecated. New tests should use the classes from  the AndroidX library. The link you give shows how to set this up. There are also training pages on how to write tests. We no longer extend `ActivityInstrumentationTestCaase` and such. Instead we use `ActivityTestRule`.

Comment: Basically I need the MockContentResolver class to test a function. I saw a way to do that on Android.test. How would I go about that without this library? Afaik AndroidX test does not have that library

Comment: @sirajnadwar You should probably ask another question showing the function you need to test.

Comment: @sirajnadwar `MockContentResolver` lives in the `android.test.mock` package. The documentation I am reading still references it, so you might be able to use it.

Comment: yes the document has it online but the android package that I have on my local machine does not. When Iook at all the android libraries on my machine I can't find the android.test library. I am not sure if I can get a stand alone library for this which I can reference. I am targetting api level 28

Comment: @sirajnadwar What do you mean by "the android package that I have on my local machine"? Where are you attempting to find this package?